# How to use mongorestore/mongodump with username and password?

Tags: mongodb

I know this is a basic security measure, but I can't make it works with my mongodb installation. Each time I run the command :

```
mongorestore dump_folder -u "username" -p "password"
```

It returns:

```
error reading database: not authorized on DATABASE_NAME to execute command { listCollections: 1, cursor: { batchSize: 0 } }
```

My question is : What is the permission that I need to enable and how ?

For the time being, I just turn off the Mongo's security in `/etc/mongod.conf` and start it back after I restore/dump my databases.

Additional Note:
This is how I prepared my databases and its user

1. I log in with my admin account, create a database, named DATABASE001
2. And create a user:

   ```
   use DATABASE001
   db.createUser({ 
     user: "USER001", 
     pwd: "mypassword",
     roles:[ { role: "readWrite", db: "DATABASE001" },"dbAdmin"  ]
   })
   ```

For roles, I add `readWrite` to DATABASE001 and also `dbAdmin`
I want this user (USER001) be able to backup or restore his database (DATABASE001).

3. I tested it by login with this command. It successfully logged in

   ```
   mongo localhost -u USER001 -p mypassword --authenticationDatabase DATABASE001
   ```
4. I want to dump this database content with:

   ```
   mongodump  -u USER001 -p mypassword --authenticationDatabase DATABASE001
   ```

   it throws me an error: 
   `Failed: error getting database names: not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1 }`

What is this `listDatabases` ? how can I add it to my roles?

Comment: Maybe you would find this in the documentation under [Required Access](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#required-access) and possibly with it's reference to the [restore role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#restore)? I mean really, I just scanned the manual page and it's pretty clear.

Comment: I read that, but don't understand. I created a user in that database with createUser() command. I also add readWrite and dbAdmin role.

Comment: I would suggest going back and taking a good look and the user accounts and their assigned roles. Like I said, the MongoDB documentation pages for both [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) and [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) have a clearly defined title link at the top of each document that leads to Required Access with each of those sections listing to the built in roles definition which also lists each individual privilege required. I'm not sure how this could be made more clear.

Comment: If this is really still a problem for you, then perhaps you should document everything you have done to set up your user(s) so it makes it clear to diagnose and/or compare with.

Comment: @NeilLunn: Fine, I just edited my question. I read the documentation and I think this should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Why would you think it should work? I just took two seconds to look over the details you added to the question and at no point do you actually assign the "built in roles" as referenced in the documentation. `dbAdmin` does not necessarily have the privileges required ( and IMHO it should not ). Read the documentation "carefully". It's the `restore` role for most restore needs or the `backup` role for most backup needs.

Answer (score 8):

```
$ mongorestore --username adminUser --password pass123 --authenticationDatabase admin --db exampleDB dump/exampleDB
```